# "An error occurred while updating the entries."

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion

I get this error from my code:
        {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

I see the inner exception and:
        {"Parameter value '99999,999' is out of range."}

but when  i upload only one archive he is fine, and when i upload more than one archive he throws the exception.

This is my code:

```
private void ProcessarCEP(int i,FileInfo file,string [] Lines)
{
    string vNomeArquivo = string.Empty;
    DBCEPEntities DBCEP = new DBCEPEntities();
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(file.DirectoryName);
    FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    int vTamanhoBase = DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Where(t => t.UF == file.Name.Substring(15,2)).Count();

    for (int a = vTamanhoBase; a < i + vTamanhoBase; a++)
        {
            if (a >= Lines.Count()) break;

            CAD_CEP CEP = new CAD_CEP();
            string[] Registros = Lines[a].Split('@');

            CEP.CEP = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[7]);
            CEP.UF = Registros[1];
            CEP.LOGRADOURO = Registros[8];
            CEP.ENDERECO = Registros[5];
            if (Registros[2] != string.Empty)
            {
                decimal CodLocal = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[2]);
                var local = DBCEP.CAD_CIDADE.Where(c => c.CODLOCAL == CodLocal).FirstOrDefault();
                CEP.LOCAL = local.LOCAL;
            }
            if (Registros[3] != string.Empty)
            {
                decimal CodBairro = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[3]);
                var bairro = DBCEP.CAD_BAIRRO.Where(c => c.CODBAIRRO == CodBairro).FirstOrDefault();
                CEP.BAIRRO = bairro.BAIRRO;
            }
            vNomeArquivo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NomeArquivoSequencia"].ToString();
            if (files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper() == vNomeArquivo.ToUpper()).Count() > 0)
            {
                if (Registros[0] != string.Empty)
                {
                    string[] LinesSec = File.ReadAllLines(files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(vNomeArquivo.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault().FullName.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
                    string vLinhaSec = LinesSec.Where(l => l.StartsWith(Registros[0] + "@")).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (vLinhaSec != null)
                    {
                        string[] vLinhaSplit = vLinhaSec.Split('@');

                        if (vLinhaSplit[1] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            CEP.DE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[1]);
                        }
                        if (vLinhaSplit[2] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            CEP.ATE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[2]);
                        }
                        CEP.FL_PAR_IMPAR = vLinhaSplit[3];
                    }
                    Registros = null;
                    LinesSec = null;
                }
            }
            DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Add(CEP);
        }
        DBCEP.SaveChanges();
        vTamanhoBase = DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Where(t => t.UF == file.Name.Substring(15, 2)).Count();
        DBCEP.Dispose();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        if (Lines.Count() <= i + vTamanhoBase)
        {
           if(vTamanhoBase != Lines.Count())
           {
               ProcessarCEP(Lines.Count() - i, file, Lines);
           }                    
        }
        else
        {
            if(vTamanhoBase != Lines.Count())
            {
                ProcessarCEP(i, file, Lines);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: DBCEP.SaveChanges();

Comment: Please identify which parameter is out of range (99999,999) and update the question.